# проблема с рассылкой

Tags: python, email, рассылка

При отправке письма через эту программу через английское имя проходит, но сразу летит в спам, русское имя вообще не поддерживает
вылазят такие ошибки
The mail system

sales.bbooom@gmail.com: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.164.26] said:
550-5.7.1 [217.144.103.44] Messages missing a valid address in From:
header, or 550 5.7.1 having no From: header, are not accepted.
z19-20020a2e9653000000b002b6cb2[image: введите сюда описание изображения]38da6si2743530ljh.365 - gsmtp (in reply to
end of DATA command)

```
from SMTPClient import SMTPClient
from Postmaster import PostmasterMail
import smtplib
import logging
import time
import datetime
import configparser
import random
from threading import Timer

# Считываем учетные данные
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini", "utf-8")

logger = logging.getLogger("SMTP_SERVER")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
logger_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger_formater = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s")
logger_handler.setFormatter(logger_formater)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler("logging.log")
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_formater = logging.Formatter(
    "%(asctime)s - [%(levelname)s] - %(name)s - %(message)s"
)
file_handler.setFormatter(file_formater)
logger.addHandler(logger_handler)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

# Присваиваем значения внутренним переменным
subject_send = config["Setting"]["subject"]
name_from = config["Setting"]["from_name"]
unsubscribe_from = config["Setting"]["list_unsubscribe"]
pausesend = config["Setting"]["pause_send"]
limitday = config["Setting"]["limit_day"]

refreshtoken = config["Postmaster"]["refresh_token"]
problem_spam6 = config["Postmaster"]["stop_problem_spam"]
spam6 = config["Postmaster"]["stop_spam"]

with open("message.html", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    messages = file.read()

with open("Server_data.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    data_server = file.read().splitlines()


def get_failes(patch):
    with open(patch, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        if not lines:
            return None
        email = lines[0]
        lines.remove(email)
        # lines.append(email)

    with open(patch, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.writelines(lines)
    return email


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lines_exists = True
    while lines_exists:
        try:
            for server in data_server:
                (server, port, login, password) = server.split("|")
                (names, domain) = login.split("@")
                from_email = f"{name_from} <{login}>"
                text_type = "html"

                postmail = PostmasterMail(refreshtoken)
                smtp = SMTPClient(
                    domain,
                    server,
                    port,
                    login,
                    password,
                    from_email,
                    unsubscribe_from,
                    text_type,
                )
                logger.info(f"Получил данные сервера: {login}")
                time.sleep(3)

                pm_static = 0
                for num in range(int(limitday)):
                    to_email = get_failes("Baza_email.txt")
                    if to_email == None:
                        logger.warning(f"Закончились email в с писке для рассылки!!!")
                    else:
                        smtp.send_messages(to_email, subject_send, messages)
                        logger.info(f"{login} - Send message OK! | To: {to_email}")

                        pause1, pause2 = pausesend.split("-")
                        time.sleep(random.randint(int(pause1), int(pause2)))
                        pm_static += 1

                        if pm_static >= 10:
                            probablyspam2, spam2 = postmail.get_statistic(domain)
                            if int(probablyspam2) >= int(problem_spam6) or int(
                                spam2
                            ) >= int(spam6):
                                logger.info(
                                    f"Проверка Postmaster: Возможно спам: ({int(probablyspam2)}) - Спам: ({int(spam2)})"
                                )
                                logger.warning(
                                    f"Остановил рассылку, пауза на 24 часа..."
                                )
                                time.sleep(5400)
                            else:
                                logger.info(
                                    f"Проверка Postmaster: Возможно спам: ({int(probablyspam2)}) - Спам: ({int(spam2)})"
                                )
                                pm_static = 0

        except smtplib.SMTPException as err:
            logger.warning(f"Ошибка отправки!|{err}")

        logger.warning(
            f"Разослал по лимитам {limitday} писем за день, пауза на 24 часа..."
        )
        time.sleep(90000)
```